# How to print / know the memory location of a variable in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have an if loop where 5 different numbers are printed, but I want to know how to also print the memory location of the data.
for example I print:

0x7ffd4b096f

0x7ffd4a09af

0x7ffd4c096f

being 3 different variables.

Comment: Hmm, the context is a bit unclear. Assuming by memory location you mean an address, not all "numbers" are going to have one (in fact, many won't). How do you know these numbers will have addresses? Are they all stored in a heap-allocated array, for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `pointer`:

```
julia> x = [1,2,3];

julia> pointer(x)
Ptr{Int64} @0x000000001bb534d0
```